# MYSQL connector.net connection lost after long time

Tags: c#, mysql, connection, connector

I have mysql connection to remote server with connector.net 6.7.4

like this:

```
public MySqlConnection conn;
public MySqlCommand com;

public onStart()
{
   conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=xx.xx.xx.xx;Port=3306;Database=kbindb;Uid=collector; Pwd=xxx;");
   conn.Open();
   com = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM blabla;", conn);
   timer.Interval=1000;
   timer.Enabled=True;

}   

public onTimerTick(bla bla)
{
    // timer.Enabled=False;
     MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
     while(dr.Read()){
            //blabla
      }
     dr.Close();
     //timer.Enabled=True;
 }
```

Code is running succesfully but after 1-2 hours lock timer on this line : com.ExecuteReader();
It can  not handling with try catch.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't keep a connection to the database open any longer than you need it.. certainly not for hours. I assume you're getting a timeout of some sort.

Try creating the connection inside the tick event, get your data, and dispose of the connection. (The `using` statements in the following code will take care of disposing your resources.)

```
public onStart()
{
   timer.Interval = 1000;

   timer.Enabled = true;
}   

public onTimerTick(...)
{
    timer.Enabled = false;

    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=xx.xx.xx.xx;Port=3306;Database=kbindb;Uid=collector; Pwd=xxx;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var com = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM blabla;", conn))
        {
            var reader = com.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //blabla
            }
        }
    }

    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I succeeded this stuff for local database. I don't know with remote databases wrong.